# Laravel elixir with sass

Tags: laravel, npm, sass

I'm trying to use [bulma](http://bulma.io/) in my project. But I get an error:

```
{ Error: resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma
       Parent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss
        on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss
>> @import "bulma"
   ^

    at options.error (/Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:283:26)
  status: 1,
  file: '/Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
  line: 1,
  column: 1,
  message: 'resources/assets/sass/app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n        on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "bulma"\n   ^\n',
  formatted: 'Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n        on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "bulma"\n   ^\n',
  messageFormatted: '\u001b[4mresources/assets/sass/app.scss\u001b[24m\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n        on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "bulma"\n   ^\n',
  messageOriginal: 'File to import not found or unreadable: bulma\nParent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
  relativePath: 'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: resources/assets/sass/app.scss\nError: File to import not found or unreadable: bulma\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n        on line 1 of resources/assets/sass/app.scss\n>> @import "bulma"\n   ^\n\n    at options.error (/Users/Janssen/Code/forumv2/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:283:26)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-sass' }
MacBook-Pro-van-Jamie:forumv2 Janssen$
```

This is how my `Gulp` file looks like:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
    mix.webpack('app.js')
        .styles([
            './node_modules/normalize-css/normalize.css',
            './node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css',
            './node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css',
            './node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css'
            ])
        .sass('app.scss');
});
```

When I try to import it in my `app.scss` like this:

```
@import "bulma"
```

I receive the above error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bulma.scss` file needs to be present in the `resources/assets/sass` directory to import if you are importing from npm package then define the full path like

`@import 'node_modules/pathtobulma.scss/bulma';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to include them in you main sass file rather in the gulp file . I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');` to `var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');` This helped me.